# How does .fullScreenCover work under the hood?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate a view modifier that acts like `fullScreenCover`. But I can't quite figure it out. This is what I've got so far:

```
extension View {
  public func foo(
    shouldPresent: Binding<Bool>
  ) -> some View {
    self.modifier(
      Bar(shouldPresent: shouldPresent)
    )
  }
}

struct Bar: ViewModifier {
  @Binding var shouldPresent: Bool

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .onReceive(Just(shouldPresent)) { _ in
        updatePresentation(shouldPresent)
      }
  }

  private func updatePresentation(_ shouldPresent: Bool) {
    if shouldPresent {
      // Do presenting here
    } else {
      // Do dismissing here
    }
  }
}
```

This is then attached as a view modifier to a view like:

```
.foo(shouldPresent: $shouldPresent)
```

What I've found though is that if the state of the view that the modifier is attached to changes, such that it re-renders, the updatePresentation function gets fired again. This isn't the intended behaviour because it should only get fired when the `shouldPresent` binding changes, not when any state in the view changes.
This leads to unexpected behaviour where my presentation/dismissal code gets fired when it shouldn't.

`fullScreenCover` doesn't seem to have this issue. How can I change my code so that it only listens to the `shouldPresent` binding?

Comment: They create new modal presentation, you don't.

Comment: @Asperi how do you mean? I’ve omitted the part where a view is presented. It’s more the underlying logic of responding to a binding that I’m having difficulty with

Comment: Enter Debug View Hierarchy mode and you'll see difference.